# Uncaught TypeError: t.setPenSIze is not a function but it is a function

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, turtle-graphics

So Im working on a Webserver (hosted locally: port 5000) and robot set up where the web server communicates with the robot (raspberrypi and brickpi robot using a variety sensor - Mostly EV3 sensors but a few other that are compatible with raspberrypi's and brick pi's)

But this isn't the problem currently Im creating a system that maps out the previous moves of the robot with Turtle but when i run it shows that their a type error within developers tool on the webserver.

[image]

But if i go into mapping.js it doesn't show the same error or even that the "i" is capitalised

```
var brd = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('Box',{boundingbox: [-250, 250, 250, -250]});
var t = brd.create('turtle',[0, 0], {strokeOpacity:0.5});
t.setPenSize(3);

function forwardturtle(results)
{
    console.log(results);
    t.forward(results.elasped*20);
}

function rotateturtle(results)
{
    console.log(results);
    t.rt(results.rotated);
}
```

This is the Dashboard page where all the command for the robot are executed and how the turtle commands are issued

```
{% extends "brickpilayout.html" %}

{% block styles %}
    <link herf="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsxgraph@1.1.0/distrib/jsxgraph.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <button id="loadbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="hideelement('loadbutton'); JSONrequest('brickpiload','POST',brickpiloadedhandler);">Load BrickPi</button>
    </div>
    <div id="stats" class="row"> <!-- recurring function - use json to fetch the voltage, currentcommand and current routine -->
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <div class="row fitrow">
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpistart','POST',forwardturtle)">Forward</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpiback','POST')">Backward</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpiturnright','POST',rotateturtle)">Turn Right</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpiturnleft','POST',rotateturtle)">Turn Left</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center fitrow">
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpishoot','POST')">Shoot Robot</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="JSONrequest('brickpistop','POST')">Stop</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="hideelement('dashboard'); JSONrequest('brickpishutdown','POST', brickpishutdownhandler);">Shutdown Robot</button>
            </div>
        <br/>
        <h2> Map </h2>
        <div id="Box" class="jxgbox" style="width:500px; height:500px;"> </div>
    </div>
</div>  
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    {% if robotenabled %} <!-- cant equate because comes in as the word 'True'-->
        <script> robotenabled = true;</script>
    {% else %}
        <script> robotenabled = false;</script>
    {% endif %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsxgraph@1.1.0/distrib/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
    <script src="static/mapping.js"></script>
    <script src="static/brickpirequesthandlers.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

if you need any more information on the code i can provide it in the comment s but the code i have i pretty expansive

EDIT: ewong here a image of the code which is the same a posted

[image]

Comment: The error is complaining about ```t.setPenSIze(3)``` not being a function.   I don't see ```t.setPenSIze(3)```.   Are you sure the code you posted is the same code that the ide is complaining about?   In the posted code, you have ```t.setPenSize(3)``` which seems correct.

Comment: So do you still have the same error?

Comment: @ewong yeah same error code

Answer (score 0):

Ok i don't know why this was happing but i simiply fixed by deleting that file and renaming it to something else and just changing all references to the old file to the new file and that fixed i have no idea why but it worked